# Sending SMS through GSM modem in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, sms, terminal, gsm

My project is a full program to communicate with a USB modem via serial port. What I am working on now is sending the SMS. What I can't figure out is what to tell it to actually send the message. I know that in terminal you would hit CTRL-z to send the message. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out using a combination of these two websites:

[Escape Sequences (C)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[ASCII Table](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html)

The ASCII escape sequence in C is '/xhh' where hh is the hexadecimal sequence, and the ASCII hex sequence for CTRL-Z is 1A, so it's just '/x1a'.